# How to get main as default branch when I turn on VCS in android studio

Tags: android, version-control, android-studio-3.0

When I enable VCS in Android Studio, it defaults to the "master" branch.
How to get "main" as the default branch?

Image for reference:

[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To name the branch `master` to `main` :

```
git branch -m master main
```

To change the default name of all your new repository :

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

If you just want to change the current branch and go to another :

```
git checkout <other branch>
```

If you want to change the current branch to another that doesn't exist, and create the new one :

```
git checkout -b <other branch>
```